# 'there is no need' vs 'there is no point'

Tags: idioms

I wonder why the example uses there is *no point* rather than, for example, *no need*. Is it because the opponent was strong and gave the winner a good run for his money?

> He has won the argument, but there is no point in rubbing his
>   opponent's nose in it

Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rub-it-in-or-rub-someone%27s-nose-in-something)

The example is from a dictionary entry. I do not know whether knowing how to use the idiom would render checking more context unnecessary.

Comment: The origin of the idiom _rub one's nose in it_ is in the mistaken belief among some dog trainers that a pup can be trained against defecating inside the residence by literally rubbing the pup's nose in his feces. (This "aversion training" has been shown to be ineffective, and in fact counterproductive, but the practice persists amongst dimwits.)

Comment: Interesting, good thing is I do not have to worry about it because I-in fact my whole family- have never had cats or dogs as pets.

Answer (score 3):

**Point** and **need** are slightly different.  [*Need* is necessity, something that obligates you to do something, or a motivation (see definition 1).](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/need)  [*Point* means something more like "the thing you are trying to achieve" (see definition 3).](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/point)

Sometimes these are very similar - for example, I need to eat because I will starve if I don't; the point of eating is to not starve.

But there are also reasons you might do something even if you don't need to - for example,  I don't *need* to walk along the waterfront today.  But the *point* of walking along the waterfront is to enjoy a pleasant evening and watch the sunset.

In the example sentence, the author is saying that there is nothing (useful) that could be achieved by rubbing the loser's nose in it.  It's true that there is also no need for it, but there could be a reason for it even if there were no need for it, so using *point* emphasizes the distinction.